# Оптимизация изображений Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel

Для загрузки изображений используются посторонняя библиотека изображение сохраняется в нескольких расширениях с учетом пропорций, это работает не плохо. Но гугл показывает что изображение можно оптимизировать. Да это действительно так но терять в качестве вообще нельзя.
Сейчас используется эта [Библиотека](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation)

Как оптимизировать изображение без потери в качестве ?

Comment: А какой библиотекой ты их сейчас ресазишь ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

Comment: Собственно я ей же это делаю, а ты устанавливаешь там качество при сжатии ? И как ты делаешь сразу их отображаешь или привьюхи все же маленькие ? может гугл говорить, что нахрена ты тип такие большие сразу грузишь ?

Comment: @Orange_shadow я не нашел как указать качество но сохраняются картинки в нескольких размерах, там где нужно достаю маленькие. еще 4 размера и оригинал сорю конечно файлами но пока что так

Comment: Уменьшай, все под тот размер который выводишь на экран, если одно и то же фото 2 раза на экране то делай по большему размеру один раз, так как раз фотка раз загрузилась второй раз она грузиться не будет так что делать одну и туже 2 раза бессмысленно, а для оригинала лучше делай ссылку на оригинальное фото, ну или подключи fancybox, правда опять же не знаю специфики

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартное сохранение данной библиотекой

```
$img = Image::make('path/to/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
$img->save('path/to/bar.jpg');
```

Управление качеством осуществляется в функции `save()`

```
$img = Image::make('path/to/foo.jpg')->resize(300, 200);
$img->save('path/to/bar.png', 60);//точнее вот тут)
```

Подробней [тут](http://image.intervention.io/api/save)